# Neigborhood of a point

Tags: general-topology

I have a homework that says the following:

> If $N_\delta(p)$ is a neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $p,$ show that it cannot intersect $E'$.

where E is a subset of R and where the set made by all the accumulation points of E is called the derivative set and it is indicated with E′

Any help in this proof would be appreciated.Thank you 
[this is my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOIeo.jpg)

Comment: Please tell us what $E'$ denotes.

Comment: @md2perpe The set made by all the accumulation points of E is called the derivative set and it is indicated with E′

Comment: So, then, what set is $E$? You just refer to it without having defined it.

Comment: @md2perpe E is a subset of R

Comment: Where $R$ is the set of real numbers, usually denoted by $\mathbb{R}$? Is $E$ an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Is $p$ related to $E$ in some way, e.g. $p \in E$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes R is the set of real numbers. I don't have information concerning E, but I guess p belongs to E

Comment: @saulspatz tI don't know.. This is how the question is asked in my homework

Comment: Is that really the whole question? Might it be a question that follows something that you have showed or talked about during a lesson?

Comment: @md2perpe No this is how it is asked. Take it as you see it is right please

Comment: Could you post a picture of the whole homework sheet?

Comment: @md2perpe sure, check the edit

Comment: Exercise 6 talks about $E$ but I don't think that $E$ in exercise 7 has to be the same as in exercise 6. However, I think that "does not intersect $p$" should be "does not intersect $E$", since that makes more sense. Thus, I think that the exercise should read "Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $N_\delta(p)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $E$. Show that it also cannot intersect $E'$."

Comment: @md2perpe yes, that must be what you said. In that case, how would we prove this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in your problem set. I *believe* this supposed to read "Let $N_\delta(p)$ be a neighborhood of $p$ that doesn't intersect $E$. Show that it cannot intersect $E'$."

We'll prove the contrapositive: Suppose $N_\delta(p) \cap E' \neq \emptyset$. So there is some $x \in N_\delta(p)$, such that $x$ is a limit point of $E$. Let $\epsilon < \delta - d(x,p)$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $E$, there is some $e \in E$ such that $e \in N_\epsilon(x)$. Can you take it from here?

---

WHY I THINK THIS IS THE CORRECT INTERPRETATION:

OP looks to be taking a first course in real analysis, which grounds the level of problem difficulty to be expected. Any neighborhood of $p$ must intersect $p$ (as I interpret this), so the problem must lie there. Note that this must mean $p \not \in E$, which would explain why the problem doesn't state $p \in E$.

Comment: yes this my first course in real analysis and yes, there might be a typo in it, so take it the way you did. I'm struggling a bit with it. If you please can provide a proof for this proposition. That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write out your thoughts and I'll help you along the way.

Comment: That's the problem, this is my first class for the neighborhood thing, so i don't have any thoughts about how to prove it. If you can solve it please, then i'll look at your steps and understand how it's done.

Comment: Here's a hint: it will be easier to prove the contrapositive. That is, let $N_\delta(p)$ intersect $E'$. Show that it also intersects $E$. Start by using the definition of the derived set, $E'$...

Comment: Can you show me how to do it please?

Comment: Can you show me that you've made an honest attempt?

Comment: yes i did. look at the edited post

Comment: @PBC I paraphrased what you wrote, and added a little to it. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: is it how i can continue it? :"but then e would also be a limit point of E and thus it would belong to E', which is a contradiction, sonce e belongs to E, thus N(p) does not intersect E'"

Comment: Not quite. we have no reason to believe $e$ is a limit point of $E$. The outline from here is: 1) show that $e \in N_\delta(p)$ using the triangle inequality. 2) conclude the proof.

Comment: please it's my first trial in proofs and I don't know much. please can you continue this proof for me?

Comment: Alright, so if $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then there are elements of $E$ that are arbitrarily close to it, right? And since $N_\delta(p)$ is open, there is a smaller neighborhood $N_\epsilon(x)$ such that $N_\epsilon(x) \subset N_\delta(p)$. So if we want to show that $E$ intersects $N_\delta(p)$, we can say...

Comment: So if we want to show that E intersects Nδ(p), we can say... ?"

Comment: What is after that sentence

Comment: That's for you to figure out. I'm not going to do your homework for you. I've already done 95%, the last 5% is for you. If you read what I've written above, I'm very confident you can figure it out.

Comment: I guess I got it.. should I continue like this?: since Nϵ(x)⊂Nδ(p) and e∈Nϵ(x) so  e must ∈ Nδ(p). We also have that e ∈ E, and thus e is a common element of E and Nδ(p) and therefore E intersects Nδ(p). We conclude that if E intersects Nδ(p), then Nδ(p) also intersects E'. Thus proving, by the contrapositive that if If Nδ(p) is a neighborhood of p that does not intersect E, then it cannot intersect E′.

Comment: Almost perfect! The only part that's wrong is that it should read, "We conclude that if $E'$ intersects $N_\delta (p)$, then $N_\delta(p)$ also intersects $E$"

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help. You really helped me a lot in this.